# Automatically remove a device from /dev

Tags: udev, devices

I am having keyboard problems, with a laptop built in keyboard. I have an external keyboard, so wish to disable the internal one.

So far I have discovered that I can disable within X11 using `xinput float …`, however this only works for X11, and the keyboard mysteriously comes back. I have also discovered that removing the device works (if done before starting X11).

I think that a `udev` rule may be the way to go. What do I need to know about the device? How do I write the rule?

Comment: I remember udev support running a command on device plug, maybe call the `rm`?